python re identifiers not working with lookahead and lookbehind
I have the following string
str = '2024-09-23 18:05:08,147 INFO  [WatchDog_191084]  (alloc:0MB, cpu:0%) 10      422'

and I am trying to extract the numbers between the squared brackets. so I am trying with
identifier_test = re.search('(?<=\[)\d+(?=])',str)
print(identifier_test)

I get None, but if I try
identifier_test = re.search('(?<=\[).+(?=])',str)
print(identifier_test.group())

it works as expected and returns WatchDog_191084.
How do I get the numbers only?

As a side note, it's bad practice to use a builtin (i.e., str) as a variable name.

Always use a raw string when creating a regexp. It's not an issue for this regexp, but can affect others.

Use the second one, then split it at _ and use the second element.

identifier_test.group().split('_')[-1]

[x[:-1] for x in re.split(r'[_\s]', text) if x.endswith(']') and all(c.isdigit() for c in x[:-1])]

With regex, you simply need re.findall(r'\[[^][]*?(\d+)]', text). Do not name your variable str as it is a built-in.

In your first pattern, nothing matches the WatchDog_ part of the input string. The lookbehind expects to find a [ character immediately before the numbers, but that's not what it finds, so the match fails. If your inputs will always have WatchDog_ in them, you can make that part of the lookbehind:
re.search(r'(?<=\[WatchDog_)\d+(?=])',str)

If you want to accept any text there, things get a little trickier. Python's re regex engine only supports fixed length lookbehinds, so something like (?<=\[[^\]\d]*) isn't allowed. In that situation, using a pattern like your second one and extracting the numeric bits with some post processing would make the most sense.
